# How to use variables while matching branches in gitlab-ci?

Tags: gitlab-ci

How can I match a branch name a variable? If I set the variable to 1.1.0 I want it to only match release branches that are for that version. I can't seem to do variable replacement here or in a regex (as seen commented out). Are there any options? The 1.1.0 would actually be coming from the project variables, not hard coded in the file so hard coding it really isn't an option here.

This does not seem to do variable replacement.

```
stages:
  - build

variables:
  buildNum: $CI_PIPELINE_ID
  stagingVersion: 1.1.0

before_script:
  - export MYTEAM_BUILD_NUM=${buildNum}
  - export MYTEAM_VERSION=${stagingVersion}

build_staging:
  stage: build
  only:
    - release/v${stagingVersion}@myTeam/myProject
    # - /^release\/v${stagingVersion}@myTeam\/myProject$/
  script:
    - doStuff
```

Comment: Idea that someone gave me: Match all branches but then check for the version inside the `script` section and exit if it doesn't match. Might hinder you from having multiple scripts though, will have to test

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with a hacky solution to achieve this. It's not great but it gets the job done. It will fail jobs that match the branch criteria but do not match the branch version criteria:

```
  only:
    - /^release\/v\d+.\d+.\d+$/@myTeam/myProject
  script:
    - if ! [ "${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}@${CI_PROJECT_PATH}" = "release/v${stagingVersion}@myTeam/myProject" ]; then echo "Staging branch? NO; Exiting"; exit 1; else echo "Staging branch? YES; Continuing"; fi
```

1. The `only` section first filters down to branches that match the `release/v0.0.0@myTeam/myProject` format
2. Then the first line of the script runs a bash command which compares the `stagingVersion` (set in gitlab project variables to the current version for the staging environment) and the `$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME`
3. If the branches match, it prints a success message, if they do not match, it runs `exit 1` and fails the build